# Reference several Class objects with one line of code (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have this code in the (ERB) view file:

```
<% if current_page?(some_object_path(some_object)) %>
          <%= f.submit "Create Some Object", class:'btn btn-success'%>
            <% else %>
              <%= f.submit "Update Some Object", class:'btn btn-info'%>
                <% end %>
```

and this:

```
<%= form_tag import_some_object_path, multipart: true do %>
          <%= file_field_tag :file, class: "" %>
            <%= submit_tag "Import CSV", class: "btn btn-info " %>
              <% end %>
```

Now, the issue is that I have several of these different paths relating to respective classes (tables in the database). I don't want to replicate these codes in all 9 Class views in the app. Is there a way to refactor this so I can reference the code in just one location (say, a _partial), and then rails knows what object to insert in the **some_object** field depending on say, the `current_page`? Is there a magic wand way to do this?

(I have really scoured the internet but I can't find a solution. It may be that I am using the wrong search terms though)

Comment: Hah, I faced this issue 6 years ago. Maybe the solution still works today. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105940/get-route-path-dynamically

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I looked up the page. The issue treated there is different from mine, I'm afraid. In my case here, the codes relate to the submit button for a form AND the import CSV form tag, respectively. I just don't want to replicate it in all 9 ERB view files since it's basically the same code with the only difference being in the object being referenced. ( I wish I know a better way to explain this)

Comment: From what fake code you've shown here, the issue looks pretty much the same. Not _identical_, of course, but like 95% the same.

Comment: Ok. I will read up on the polymorphic_url to see if I can figure it out

Comment: Read other code in that thread as well. All three snippets solved my problem there, but not all may be equally useful in your situtation.